# Python - why is my for loop giving me a ValueError?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm reading a text file of about 41 lines.
It reads/prints them all just fine, but when it gets to the end... it gives me this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I thought my for loop corrected for that. What am I doing wrong?

```
line = infile.readline()

while line != '':
    amount = int(infile.readline())
    print(amount)
```

Comment: dont' use while loops to iterate over files, file objects are iterators, you can just use a for-loop to iterate over them directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
        amt = int(line)
        print(amt)
```

Comment: Wow, that was awesome. Thank you Seth.

Comment: Did the line.strip() just strip away all the extra info (like newline), so it was just the data?

Comment: Yes, it does. :)